# What class id the typeahead dropdown in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using twitter bootstrap on my site and using a css template I purchased. Unfortunately when using typeahead the drop down appears the hover/ focused choice on the drop down is too dark and obscures my text.  The text is black and the background is a very dark grey on my hover / focus so the text is unredeable

I tried modifying dropdown-menu .active > a:hover and the color attribute for almost everything I could see with drop down in it, but that didn't change the text color. I must be missing something easy

Also when I try clicking on it to choose inspect element in chrome it disapears unfortunately

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a promising start for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/SDLpt/

The hover background is actually a gradient. I've changed the default hover background to #aaa and the default hover text colour to red and everything looks good.

***CSS***

```
.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: 0;
 background-color: #aaa;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aaa, #aaa);
 .....
 }
```

Good luck!

Comment: David, big thank you for that. That is exactly what I needed. I should have used JS fiddle rather than the browser. Big thank you!